# 'Wrapping up' term

Tags: word-choice

When I start a task: that is called the PREPARATION PHASE.
When I do the task: that is called the EXECUTION PHASE

So, how would a say, correctly, when it is the WRAPPING UP PHASE.  I know wrapping up is not a correct and professional term for calling this phase, so what would it be?

English is not my 1st language, so I am trying to figure this out.

Thanks for your assistance.
Claudia

Comment: I think the answer to this question lies in knowing more detail: what exactly happens during the "wrapping up" phase? Recording data? Writing reports? Testing? Cleaning dishes?

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.  In the case of the dishes, the "wrapping up" would be: putting dishes away. (You're wrapping up your task), but I didn't want to use the term 'wrapping up' since it sounds very 'low class', LOL.  Well, that's what I think.

Answer (score 1):

How about Conclusion, or Concluding Phase?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, that sounds more professional instead of calling it, the 'wrapping up' phase. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Would *terminal phase* work in your context?

Comment: Yes, that sounds more professional than calling it the 'wrapping up' phase.  Thank you so much for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

How about

> Closing Phase
>
> Final Phase
>
> Completion Phase

Would any of these suit? They're generic enough to apply to most activities.

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance.  Yes, that sounds much better than 'wrapping it up'. That was exactly what I was looking for.  Thx again.

Comment: You're welcome. You will get some extra reputation points for marking one of these answers as correct - whichever you found the most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The terms **[follow-up](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/follow-up_1)** or **[follow through](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/follow-through)** are often used to describe post execution stages.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, when you prepare for the task is PREPARATION STAGE, then THE EXECUTION STATE, but when you are finishing and cutting '

Comment: ends. That is what I mean by the WRAPPING UP STAGE.  I think a 'FOLLOW-UP' OR FOLLOW THROUGH would be that you are still working on it.  So WRAPPING it UP in this case means finishing the task, without following it through.  Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Finishing Phase? Reflection Phase? If it's not actually the final phase you could Penultimate Phase.

Comment: Finishing face would be more suitable. It should be the last phase, that is when you have to do the 'wrapping up' of things so it can be done or finished.  Thank you so much for your contribution.